# Laravel get the route that do the POST or GET request laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am trying to get the source of the url that does the request POST/GET to a route. For example:

```
Route::post('/do-something', somethingController@getWhoRequesting);
```

Then as example, on the view I do ajax or a simple form post to that route, which is from localhost:8888/my-web-view. How do I get the url of who is requesting to my /do-something endpoint? I expect on `getWhoRequesting()`, but I get the '/my-web-view'.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get full url from requestin controller using request

```
request()->fullUrl();  or $request->fullUrl();
```

Updates:

If you want to capture all request then you can create middleware and assign it to all routes

```
php artisan make:middleware  RequestCapture
```

then file will be look like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class RequestCapture
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

       //here you can capture all $request for assigned middleware routes

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Also register this middleware in `kernal.php` in `protected $routeMiddleware`

```
 'requestCapture' => \App\Http\Middleware\RequestCapture::class,
```

then you can assign to routegroup

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'requestCapture'], function () {

});
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't want to get 'do-something' when i hit 'do-something' , i want to get 'my-web-view', the route which hit the POST endpoint

Comment: you can capture in middleware like updated my post

Answer (score 1):

You could use path method of Laravel. The path method returns the request's path information. So, if the incoming request is targeted at http://example.com/foo/bar, the path method will return foo/bar:

```
$uri = $request->path();
```

I hope it is something you are looking for ??